# Clang compiler/Linker cannot find symbol NSMenuItem for x86_64 Architechture

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, sdl-2

I'm currently porting a C++/SDL2 application to Mac OS X and I want to add items to and edit the native Menu Bar that accompanies Mac OS X applications (at the top of the screen).

However, my compiler is complaining about not recognizing the NSMenuItem class anywhere within the Cocoa API...

I've managed to convert my main.cpp to main.mm and #import Cocoa/Cocoa.h headers, however when I declare an NSMenuItem variable (Such as the LoadROMItem varialbe in my snippet below) I get a linker error :

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMenuItem", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Here's the code snippet:

```
    bool RUNNING = true;
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Window* _SDLwindow = SDL_CreateWindow("GBemu", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 500, 500, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
    SDL_Surface* _screen = SDL_GetWindowSurface(_SDLwindow);
    SDL_SysWMinfo *NativeWindowInfo = new SDL_SysWMinfo;
    SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(_SDLwindow, NativeWindowInfo);

    SDL_Event _event;

#ifdef __APPLE__
    NSMenuItem* LoadRomItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Load ROM" action:NULL keyEquivalent:@"s"];
    [NativeWindowInfo->info.cocoa.window.menu addItem:LoadRomItem];
#endif
```

Could this be due to something im forgeting to import? Or is it perhaps a compiler and/or linker setting I am forgetting to set?

I'm using XCode as my IDE of choice.

Answer (score 0):

This is a linker error, not a compiler error.  Make sure you link against the Cocoa framework - in Xcode you can just add it to your project.